# How to move items(menu) inside QMenuBar?

Tags: python, pyside

Today , I was wondering how can I move menu items inside QMenuBar.
I wanted to make one menu(self.***.addMenu('test')) on the left side where it is usually would be going by default and two other menus on the right. I was trying few commands inside QWidget , like 'move' or adding separators , but it doesn't seem to work. My guess is that I have to use self.setStyleSheet, but I am not really good at it and I couldn't find any information related to my guess in the internet. Can somebody give me some advise where to look or how to do it ? Thank you.

Comment: From what I understand you want some menus aligned to the left and others aligned to the right of the menubar. Am I correct? Or do you want all the menus to the right of the menubar?

Comment: I want to move some menus to the left and to the right.

Comment: The "move" sounds confusing since it can be confused with dragging a menu from right to left, do you want to drag or want to place the menus to the right since by default they are aligned to the left?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want to place some to the left and some to the right, because they are all by default left side. No dragging , nothing fancy , just simply like putting menu "File" , "View" to the left and "General" , "Help" to the right. Is it possible ?